# Serving multiple apis in google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to serve 2 different api's with a different set of methods as documented here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/deploying-apis-subdomains

via GCE, that are structured as below in my main.py

```
@endpoints.api(name = 'first', version = 'v1')
class firstApi(remote.Service):
  @endpoints.method(
    # Lots of stuff here
    path = 'first'
    # Lots more here

@endpoints.api(name = 'second', version = 'v1')
class secondApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(
      # Lots of stuff here
      path = 'second'
      # Lots more here

api = endpoints.api_server([firstApi, secondApi])
```

but when I generate firstv1openapi.json and secondv1openapi.json and deploy them, something strange happens. When I load it up in Google's API explorer, I see **both** methods under **both** API's

What is worse, is when I click on the 2nd API, and try any of the methods via the API explorer, the path always references the 1st API.

POST https://my_backend_here.appspot.com/_ah/api/**first**/v1/**second**

which as expected fails with a 404.

I've looked at both firstv1openapi.json and secondv1openapi.json to see if the api's cross reference each other at all, and they both look fine.

I'm out of trying different options, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using the Python Endpoints Framework. The Framework currently works only in App Engine's Standard environment, not in GCE.